# Node JS "Cannot use import statement outside a module" but package.json includes the module type

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

So I'm using node JS to access different API's since I'm very new to javascript. My library of choice is [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios). To make sure it works I made this extremely basic script:

*index.js*

```
console.log("Getting axios")
const axios = require("axios")
console.log("Got it")
```

but I get this on my output:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError C:\Users\<name>\Downloads\PostJs\node_modules\axios\index.js:1
import axios from './lib/axios.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at Module._compile (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Module._extensions..js (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Module._load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.require (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:852:19)
    at require (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at <anonymous> (c:\Users\<name>\Downloads\PostJs\index.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:959:30)
    at Module._extensions..js (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Module._load (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Module.runMain (<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at <anonymous> (<node_internals>/internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11)
```

*Of course I replaced my name with `<name>` because I'm not trying to dox myself*

Anyway, a quick search told me to go to my `package.json` file and add `"type": "module"` to it, which I did to get this:

package.json

```
{
  "name": "postjs",
  "type": "module",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC"
}
```

but nothing changes. I think I did everything I was supposed to but now I'm at a loss. Why is this happening?

If it helps, here is what my file explorer looks like:

[image: Looks okay I think]

Comment: Have you saved the changes to `package.json`? You should get an error for `const axios = require("axios")`. You can't use `require` in an ES module. https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-gjj55q?file=index.js,package.json You didn't set the type correctly.

Comment: If you're using `require`, **your** `package.json` shouldn't have `"type": "module"` in it (and you shouldn't get the error you described when you `require("axios")`). And I don't get that error if I try to replicate what you had before you added `"type": "module"` -- I created a new project, added the axios dependency you have listed above, did an `npm i`, and ran an `index.js` using `require("axios")` and got back a function just fine. This suggests to me there's some problem with your project setup that isn't in the question.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I tried to re-make my entire folder. I made a new folder, I ran `npm init` and `npm install axios` and I changed the script to not use `require` but instead, `import axios from "axios"`

but I still get the same error. **Edit**: Its actually not the same. This is the new error: https://pastebin.com/Bq21W6Mq

Comment: "You didn't set the type correctly." Either you wrote it into the wrong `package.json` or you didn't save the file (do you have a large white dot next to the filename?). Your problem isn't reproducible. I've created a new project, copied your code and can't reproduce the problem. See the link in my first comment. Your code produces the error message `Error: require is not defined`.

Comment: @Exilon - *"and I changed the script to not use require"* Why? As I told you above, if you want to use `require`, you can. Just don't put `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. (Or alternatively: Put `"type": "module"` in `package.json` and use `import axios from "axios";`.)

Comment: I've tried both. I added `"type": "module"` and used `import`. I also tried removing `"type": "module"` and using `require` but it still wont work :(.

Comment: Are you in the correct directory? Do you see changes when you modify `console.log("Getting axios")` to `console.log("TEST!!!")`

Comment: @ThomasSablik If you mean change in output, yes, line 1 works fine and I can print things just fine. Its just getting the library thats causing trouble for some reason.

Comment: But for some reason Node.js ignores the line `"type": "module",`. The error message in your question can't be reproduced with the posted code. Two people copied and pasted your code. The posted code produces `Error: require is not defined`, not `SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module`.

Comment: @ThomasSablik As mentioned earlier, I ditched `"type": "module",` because apparently `require` only works without it.

Comment: @Exilon - I have no idea what's going on, but it's something *unusual*, because again, doing this works just fine (on a \*nix machine): https://pastebin.com/P2kkj1j1 On a Windows machine: https://pastebin.com/FkDZpNch

Comment: @T.J.Crowder `npm i axios` gives me this: https://pastebin.com/cpushs0E. I followed everything you did on the windows pastebin. Is that anything to worry about?

Comment: @Exilon - No, not at all. Just update the `package.json` at some point.

Comment: Hmmm. Then what the hell is causing the problem. I'm struggling to find any ideas online. I might just re-install node.js tomorrow and see how that goes. If it works, I'll make it an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I checked my node js version and I was using Node v12. I downloaded the newest (stable) release and it works fine!